# Problems with CSS in Offline KnockoutJS App

Tags: html, knockout.js, coffeescript, html5-appcache

We've developed a knockout app using html5 appcache, everything works fine except the CSS. The CSS is loaded from the appcache as expected when offline and the first view is fine with everything displaying correctly. The problem starts when I update a binding and move into a new view, most (not all) of the CSS styling is lost.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Or have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you post some code or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thnaks. The project will be open sourced, so the code is available to view here, I'm not sure which part to point to as any view change causes the problem: https://bitbucket.org/ilab/resource_map_sea/src/93a047185ea9a41d502a21b53057f590abbc0377/app/assets/javascripts/mobile?at=default

Comment: Sorry Chris, I'm afraid I'm no good with coffeeScript.  If your site was running somewhere I could probably troubleshoot in the browser, but I'm sorry to say I won't be much help with the code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention CoffeeScript. I didn't choose the tech, in my experience using all the latest fads in one project is rarely a good idea, you end up with impossible to track down problems like this one.

Comment: No problem Chris.  I hope a coffeScript guru catches your question with the new tags!